# Find default network route IP address

Tags: go, docker

How can I find the default network route IP address from Go? I have looked through the docs for the net and interfaces package but didn't see anything that could do this. I wanted to avoid running a bash command if possible.

Comment: I don't think there is. It's very platform specific and requires dealing with syscalls or connecting to special sockets. It's not that easy even in C. It will be much easier to just execute something depending on OS and parse it's output.

Comment: Could you give an example? All of our go code will either be ran in a ubuntu environment or a docker.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested in the comment by @creker you could parse the output from e.g. on any linux system which has the default tools (ip head and sed).

```
ip route show match 0.0.0.0
```

... or if you want to do the parsing in the system-call and just read the output (which will be the lowest metric default route):

```
ip route show match 0.0.0.0 | head -1 | sed -E 's/.*\svia\s+//' | sed -E 's/\s.*//'
```

*(since I don't give the full answer including the go-code here I would have posted this as a comment if I had enough reputation :-) ... feel free to convert it to a comment)*